# ListFilesAndDirectories() to fetch List of files present in Azure File Share is throwing error

Tags: azure, azure-files, fileshare

For below Code Snippet `ListFilesAndDirectories()` is throwing error:

```
//***** Get list of all files/directories on the file share *****//

// List all files/directories under the root directory.
Console.WriteLine("Getting list of all files/directories under the root directory of the share.");

IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = cloudFileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().ListFilesAndDirectories();

// Print all files/directories listed above.
foreach (IListFileItem listItem in fileList)
{
  // listItem type will be CloudFile or CloudFileDirectory.
  Console.WriteLine("    - {0} (type: {1})", listItem.Uri, listItem.GetType());

}
```

`ListFilesAndDirectories();` is throwing error as

> "'CloudFileDirectory' does not contain a definition for 'ListFilesAndDirectories' and no accessible extension method 'ListFilesAndDirectories' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudFileDirectory' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: To enable us to help you, provide us with some more information than only some code and the error it throws. Please refer to [ask]. On-topic: the error you're getting is that the method you're trying to call (`ListFilesAndDirectories`) doesn't exist.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SDK version you're using.

Comment: Looking at the [`ListFilesAndDirectories()` method definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.file.cloudfiledirectory.listfilesanddirectories), it looks like you might need to add some parameters to the call.

Comment: Also, include the code that creates **cloudFileShare**. I think you are using the wrong class.